# Why is this line not being reached in my do while loop?

Tags: java, do-while

This is my method

```
private int GetJudges()
{
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of judges. This number must be between 3 and 6");   

        while(!scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please ensure the number you entered is between 3 and 6");
        }
        numJudges = scan.nextInt();

    } while (!(numJudges >=3 && numJudges<=6));

    return numJudges ;
}
```

When I enter as number below or above 3 and 6 this line is printed:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the number of judges. This number must be between 3 and 6");
```

Instead of:

```
 System.out.println("Please ensure the number you entered is between 3 and 6");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop only apply when you enter something which is not a number :

```
while(!scan.hasNextInt())
{
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please ensure the number you entered is between 3 and 6");
}
```

If you enter a number below 3 or above 6, for example 7. There is no reason you enter this loop.

---

What you want to do is more like :

```
System.out.println("Please enter the number of judges.");  
do
{
    System.out.println("Please ensure the number you entered is between 3 and 6");
    while(!scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please ensure the number you entered is a number");
    }
    numJudges = scan.nextInt();

} while (!(numJudges >=3 && numJudges<=6));
```

Though this code could be reduced to only one loop.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now, The inner while loop is only checking for integers not whether there in the correct range.